# MouseLeave in silverlight(Windows Phone 7) getting fired event if mouse hasn't moved out

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7

Register for MouseDown and MouseLeave events
this.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown);
this.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeave);

Click somewhere
both events will get fired.

shouldn't mouseleave get fired only when i move outside the boundary of the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there isn't an actual mouse on a touch based screen then this behaviour is correct.

You probably shouldn't use mouseLeave in a mobile app which doesn't use a mouse. There are a few reason why you may need to but they're not related to clicking.